# ESTA application with passport issued in UK

Tags: visa, usa, esta

If I'm an Australian citizen, I need to apply for an [ESTA](http://www.esta.us/application.html) before flying to the US for a week-long conference. I'm travelling on an Australian passport, which I recently renewed while I was studying in the UK (I lodged an application to the London passport office).

So when I fill in the ESTA form below, what do I put as the answer for "What country issued your passport?" Is it "GBO" or just Australia?

[image: esta application form]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an Australian passport, so the answer is "Australia."

Comment: This. But also just to clarify: just because the passport was issued *in* the UK, does not mean it was issued *by* the UK.